# How to launch web tabs running in Chrome's App mode at specific locations on a screen?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, google-chrome, webapps

I have a number of Chrome tabs running in app mode that I autostart on login. I have the Auto Move windows extensions able to move them to specific workspaces. I am trying to get them to next be at specific locations within a workspace. I was intending to use the Put Windows extension but that does not seem to be able to distinguish between these tabs/apps as being independent applications and seems to be apply a single rule for all Google chrome tabs/apps.

Is there a way to get these tabs/apps to be moved to specific locations within a workspace?

Here's the command pattern in desktop files that I use where the URL points to different places such as GMail, Slack, Drive, etc.

`/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app="url"`

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1329380/968501) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position and size of each window by adding the `--window-position` and `--window-size` arguments to your shortcuts.

For example:

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app="url" --window-position=0,0 --window-size=400,300
```